# How to run a python script with cmd.exe and make it invisible

Tags: cmd.exe

How do I run an invisible cmd.exe command?

Example:

> C:\Python27\tool.py

and make it visible after a while?

I tried some methods that I found on Google but I'm not very satisfied. I do not have administrative rights on this PC either if that makes a difference.

Comment: What's up!! Muntean Cosmin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to run invisible a cmd.exe command,example:

Below is one example you may find works as you describe:

1. You will have the batch file with the below logic named `tool.bat`

   - > ```
     > @ECHO OFF
     > python "C:\Python27\tool.py"
     > EXIT /B
     > ```

---

2. You will have a VBS file with the below logic named `tool.vbs`

*Ensure the path below in the `C:\tool.bat` part is pointed to the correct path to the batch file*

- > ```
  > Set WinScriptHost = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  > WinScriptHost.Run Chr(34) & "C:\tool.bat" & Chr(34), 0
  > Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
  > ```

---

3. You will then execute the `tool.vbs` file and your process should run hidden.

---

> make it visible after a while?

### To run python script with cmd and show output

```
CMD /K START "" "C:\Python27\tool.py‌​"
```

Comment: how are u?u tried something?

Comment: 'please try this weekdn do not forget me,ur my only hope...and i really need this thing!!!please try when u have a bit free time